# bash trying to pass in a variable into curl command

Tags: bash, curl

Im trying to use variables inside a curl command and i either get one of the two following:

1. test.sh line 32: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `` `"' ``

   test.sh line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file
2. `"$key"`

My command is:

```
curl 'http://1.1.1.1:8080/v2-beta/projects/1a25/stack' -H 'content-type: application/json' -data-binary $'{"system":true,"type":"stack","name":"ecr","startOnCreate":true,"environment":{"key_id":"$key","access_key":"214356","aws_region":"ap-southeast-2","auto_create":"false","log_level":"INFO","registry_in_which_environment":"current","environment_api_endpoint":"12345.dkr.amazonaws.com","environment_api_access_key":"7AC2D3FE5A1C12345","environment_api_secret_key":"QMmwp7ebmzK1ZcUCjoRM12345"},"dockerCompose":"ecr-updater:\\n  environment:\\n    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${aws_access_key_id}\\n    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${aws_secret_access_key}\\n    AWS_REGION: ${aws_region}\\n    AUTO_CREATE: ${auto_create}\\n    LOG_LEVEL: ${log_level}\\n    {{- if eq .Values.registry_in_which_environment \\"other\\" }}\\n    CATTLE_URL: ${environment_api_endpoint}\\n    CATTLE_ACCESS_KEY: ${environment_api_access_key}\\n    CATTLE_SECRET_KEY: ${environment_api_secret_key}\\n    {{- end }}\\n  labels:\\n    io.rancher.container.pull_image: always\\n    {{- if eq .Values.registry_in_which_environment \\"current\\" }}\\n    io.rancher.container.create_agent: \'true\'\\n    io.rancher.container.agent.role: environment\\n    {{- end }}\\n  tty: true\\n  image: rancher/rancher-ecr-credentials:v2.0.1\\n  stdin_open: true\\n","rancherCompose":".catalog:\\n  name: \\"ECR Credential Updater\\"\\n  version: \\"v2.0.1\\"\\n  description: \\"Updates credentials for ECR in Rancher\\"\\n  minimum_rancher_version: \\"v1.6.13-rc1\\"\\n  questions:\\n    - variable: \\"aws_access_key_id\\"\\n      label: \\"AWS Access Key ID\\"\\n      description: \\"AWS API Access Key to use for obtaining ECR credentials. Not required if using IAM roles.\\"\\n      required: false\\n      type: \\"string\\"\\n    - variable: \\"aws_secret_access_key\\"\\n      label: \\"AWS Secret Access Key\\"\\n      description: \\"AWS API Secret Key to use for obtaining ECR credentials. Not required if using IAM roles.\\"\\n      required: false\\n      type: \\"string\\"\\n    - variable: \\"aws_region\\"\\n      label: \\"AWS Region\\"\\n      description: \\"AWS Region that hosts the ECR\\"\\n      default: us-east-1\\n      required: true\\n      type: \\"string\\"\\n    - variable: \\"auto_create\\"\\n      label: \\"Auto Create\\"\\n      description: \\"Automatically create registry in Rancher for corresponding ECR repo if it doesn\'t already exist\\"\\n      default: \\"false\\"\\n      required: true\\n      type: \\"string\\"\\n    - variable: \\"log_level\\"\\n      label: \\"Log Level\\"\\n      description: \\"Logging level to run service at\\"\\n      default: \\"INFO\\"\\n      required: true\\n      type: \\"string\\"\\n    - variable: \\"registry_in_which_environment\\"\\n      type: enum\\n      label: \\"Registry Environment\\"\\n      description: \\"Which environment is the AWS registry located?\\"\\n      default: current\\n      options:\\n        - current\\n        - other\\n    - variable: \\"environment_api_endpoint\\"\\n      label: \\"URL (Environment API Endpoint) of Registry to be Updated\\"\\n      description: \\"URL for where the registry is located. This is the endpoint, which can be found under the Advanced Options under API -> Keys, for an Environment API Key.\\"\\n      default: \\"\\"\\n      required: false\\n      type: \\"string\\"\\n    - variable: \\"environment_api_access_key\\"\\n      label: \\"Access Key of an Environment API Key\\"\\n      description: \\"This access key must be for the environment where the registry will need to be updated. This access key will be created in the same environment listed for the URL. This can be created in the Advanced Options under API.\\"\\n      default: \\"\\"\\n      required: false\\n      type: \\"string\\"\\n    - variable: \\"environment_api_secret_key\\"\\n      label: \\"Secret Key of an Environment API Key\\"\\n      description: \\"This secret key must be for the environment where the registry will need to be updated. This secret key will be created in the same environment listed for the URL. This can be created in the Advanced Options under API.\\"\\n      default: \\"\\"\\n      required: false\\n      type: \\"string\\"\\necr-updater:\\n  scale: 1\\n","externalId":"catalog://library:infra*ecr:1"}'
```

Comment: (1) Show us the command that you are actually using. 
 What is in the question now won't generate the messages you show.  (2) When you want help with an error message,  __always__ provide the __full and complete__ error message, not just the parts you think might be important.

Comment: sorry still totally new at this.. added the full curl command

Comment: Variable references (e.g `$key`) don't expand in `$'...'`

Comment: There's no URL for `curl` to request; you only have a giant JSON blob that would usually be the argument to the `-d` option.

Answer (score 0):

In the following curl you will see two working variables:

1. $backup_hash without double quotes
2. $index with double quotes inside a JSON

`curl -k -XPOST 'somesite/_snapshot/cs-automated/'"$backup_hash"'/_restore' -d '{"indices": "'"$index"'"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Use an editor with syntax highlight to ensure your code is not broken:

[image]